# Sum of residuals using lm is non-zero

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have defined two variables `x` and `y`. I want to regress `y` on `x`, but the sum of residuals using the `lm` is non-zero

Here are the variables:

```
x<-c(1,10,6,4,3,5,8,9,0,3,1,1,12,6,3,11,15,5,10,4)    
y<-c(2,3,6,7,8,4,2,1,0,0,6,1,3,5,2,4,1,0,1,9)
gh<-lm(y~x)

sum(gh$residuals)
# [1] 4.718448e-16
```

I don't understand why the sum of residuals is non-zero. It should be zero by the procedure of OLS.

Thanks

Comment: 4e-16 is basically zero considering the floating point accuracy ([somehow related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal))

Comment: For fun, have you have tried to do `0.1+0.1+0.1 == 3` ? Well, it returns `FALSE` :)

Answer (score 3):

[Floating-point numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) have limited precision. Only a finite set of real numbers can be represented exactly as 32- or 64-bit floats; the rest are approximated by rounding them to the nearest number that *can* be represented exactly.

This means that, while mathematically the residuals should sum up to zero, in computer representation they might not.

I highly recommend [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).